# ts-mocha and chai - error TS2695: Left side of comma operator is unused and has no side effects

Tags: reactjs, typescript, mocha.js, chai

Tool/Lib Versions:

```
"ts-mocha": "^8.0.0",
"ts-node": "^10.3.0",
"chai": "^4.3.4",
```

Code:

```
expect(wrapper.find(MyListItem)).to.have.length(3);
```

Command:

```
ts-mocha tests/**/*.tsx  -r unitTestSetup.ts
```

My typescript compiler options:

```
{
"compilerOptions": {
  "target": "es5",
  "module": "commonjs",
  "declaration": true,
  "outDir": "./lib",
  "strict": true,
  "esModuleInterop": true,
},
```

Error:

```
tests/index.spec.tsx:41:10 - error TS2695: Left side of comma operator is unused and has no side effects.
41         (0, chai_1.expect)(wrapper.find(MyListItem)).to.have.length(3);
```

This seems to be caused by if an optional dependency for ts-mocha is not installed. (`tsconfig-paths`)

Is there a better way to fix this than doing a `npm install --force` on the ts-mocha package to force it to install tsconfig-paths? (the answer I provided)

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue with plain mocha, using ts-node.
The reason was code *infection* by an ES module package.
See also [here](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node/issues/935).

Some people try to switch to ES modules like [here](https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/issues/4726) but this didn't work for me as I still had mostly commonjs modules.

My solution was to get rid of the npm package using the ES module (i.e. having `"type": "module"` in `package.json`).

Answer (score 1):

Finally found the solution. (Tried with both `mocha` and `ts-mocha`, fix works for both).

It worked for me when I set
`"module": "ESNext"`
in the ts config file

and `"type": "module",` in the `package.json`.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by creating a 'fix-ts-mocha' script in my `package.json` file:

```
"fix-ts-mocha": "cd node_modules && cd ts-mocha && npm install --force"
```

I run this once after `npm install` (or each time `ts-mocha` is updated).